# How to align a UITableView's text?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

In my app I have a UITableView and I want to change the text's alignment to center (not only from the sides like this

```
     cell.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

but from up and down, as well).

Can you help me?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please clarify the question? If you use `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` and increase cell height something like

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  return 100;
}
```

then the label will be vertically centered without any effort on your part.

Also, `cell.textAlignment = …` is deprecated in favor of `cell.textLabel.textAlignment = …`.

Comment: Really, maybe it's a bit unclear. I want the rows to be displayed in the center of the screen, so if I have one row, it will be in the center, if I have three rows, the second one will be in the center of the screen and so on

Answer (score 1):

This will do it, assuming you are using textLabel for your text.

> cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter